# pandas create dataframe auto index disable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Is there a way to tell pandas not to index by character columns? My code is

```
A=['a','b','c']
B=[1,2,3]
pd.DataFrame(A,B)
   0
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

What I want is just two columns so I can do groupby column A. How do I go about doing this? I can do something like this but I would like to skip the column names to gain as much performance as possible.

```
pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B})
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame([A, B]).T` should give you what you want.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(list(zip(A,B)))`

Comment: Both works. but I get an error when I try to group by 0 like this pd.DataFrame([A,B]).T.groupby(0).mean(). I think it is losing types when it is transposed.

Comment: When you say, "so I can do groupby column A," what do you mean? What does your desired output look like?

Comment: 'pd.DataFrame(list(zip(A,B))).groupby(0, as_index=False).mean()' ?

Comment: I am fine with what it gives me  pd.DataFrame(list(zip(A,B))).groupby(0).mean() but doing list and zip seems to take more time than just doing pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B}).groupby('A').mean(). My thought process is given that I don't care about the column names here I would like to drop them to speed up the process

Comment: "but I would like to skip the column names to gain as much performance as possible" can you explain this? How can passing column names affect performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're actually dealing with only two columns, you can group one series by another.

```
In [6]: A = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']

In [7]: B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [8]: pd.Series(B).groupby(A).mean()
Out[8]: 
a    0.5
b    2.5
c    4.5
dtype: float64
```

I've provided some timings below.

```
In [9]: %timeit pd.Series(B).groupby(A).mean()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B}).groupby('A').mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.66 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(list(zip(A, B))).groupby(0).mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop
```